# Django-rest-framework hyperlinkedmodelserializer and foreignkey cities-light

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just installed django-cities-light for my project using DRF and I can't get it work.

My User Model define a city and coutry field as foreignkey, and this is what i get when i tried to get my users :

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "city-detail".
You  may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the lookup_field attribute on this field.
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you include your urls file, including the routers if you are using them?

Answer (score 0):

Using django-cities-light with Rest Framework 3, you need to use their provided view_name:

**cities-light-api-{model}-detail**

```
class FooSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = relations.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="foo-detail")
    city = relations.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name="cities-light-api-city-detail", queryset=City.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I figured it out since ! I even contributed the DRF 3 support into cities-light in the meantime ;)

Comment: That's super cool! (I am using django-cities-light and I am heavily relying on your DRF 3 support.) Keep on being great! :D